# cdm-schema.microsoft.com/logical is down. What is the workaround?

Tags: apache-spark

When using the spark-cdm-connector it should default to cdm-schema.microsoft.com when a local copy of the cdm root schemas are not available.
However, the site went down earlier today and now the app doesn't work.

Comment: Are you dependent on Azure (Databricks)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/lakehouse-architecture/reliability/best-practices